# Finding checkbox value, writing to XML result

Tags: xml, forms, asp-classic, checkbox

I'm creating a weekly HTML email writing template (hence the weird file name) and I'm using ASP and XML as the backend. The XML is prefect but the ASP isn't..

What I'm going for here is to create an XMl node that has a value of notchecked and checked depending on if the checkbox on the form is checked or not.

I've tried using

```
If Request.QueryString("promotioncheck") = "on" Then
        Set objField = objDom.createElement("promotioncheck")
        objField.Text = "checked"
        objRecord.appendChild objField
Else
        Set objField = objDom.createElement("promotioncheck")
        objField.Text = "notchecked"
        objRecord.appendChild objField
        End If
```

but when I do it doesn't pick up the changes and just outputs notchecked even when the checkbox is checked.

Here's my ASP:

```
<%
If Request.Form("hidden") = "true" Then
    Dim objDom
    Dim objRoot
    Dim objRecord
    Dim objField
    Dim objFieldValue
    Dim objattID
    Dim objattTabOrder
    Dim objPI
    Dim blnFileExists
    Dim x
    Dim z
    Set objDom = server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objDom.preserveWhiteSpace = True



    blnFileExists = objDom.LoadXML(server.mappath("./")& "/eg"&Day(Date)&"_"&Month(Date)&".xml")


    If blnFileExists = True Then

    For x = 1 To Request.Form.Count

    If instr(1,Request.Form.Key(x),"hidden") = 0 Then
        Set z = objDom.selectNodes("eg/stories/"&Request.Form.Key(x))
        Response.Write(Request.Form.Key(x))
        z.innerText = Request.Form(x)
    End If
Next 
Else

    Set objRoot = objDom.createElement("eg")
    objDom.appendChild objRoot
    Set objRecord = objDom.createElement("stories")
    objRoot.appendChild(objRecord)
    For x = 1 To Request.Form.Count


    If instr(1,Request.Form.Key(x),"hidden") = 0 Then
        Set objField = objDom.createElement(Request.Form.Key(x))
        objField.Text = Request.Form(x)
        objRecord.appendChild objField
    End If
    Next
    If Request.QueryString("promotioncheck") = "on" Then
        Set objField = objDom.createElement("promotioncheck")
        objField.Text = "checked"
        objRecord.appendChild objField
    Else
    Set objField = objDom.createElement("promotioncheck")
        objField.Text = "notchecked"
        objRecord.appendChild objField
        End If
End If
If blnFileExists = False then

    Set objPI = objDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")

    objDom.insertBefore objPI, objDom.childNodes(0)
End If


objDom.save (server.mappath("./")& "/eg"&Day(Date)&"_"&Month(Date)&".xml")



Set objDom = Nothing
Set objRoot = Nothing
Set objRecord = Nothing
Set objField = Nothing
Set objFieldValue = Nothing
Set objattID = Nothing
Set objattTabOrder = Nothing
 Set objPI = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
End If
%>
```

And heres the HTML form that has the checkbox

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
     <title>EG Editor</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var number_of_nibs = 1;

     function addnib(){
     number_of_nibs ++;
     var title = document.createElement('h2');
     title.innerHTML = "Story" + number_of_nibs;
     var nibformtitle = document.createElement('p');
     nibformtitle.innerHTML = "Title:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"nib"+   number_of_nibs +"_title\" style=\"width: 400px;\">";
     var nibformcontent = document.createElement('p');
      nibformcontent.innerHTML = "Content:<br><textarea cols=\"22\" rows=\"7\" name=\"nib"+ number_of_nibs + "_content\" style=\"width: 400px;\"></textarea>";
     var smallnewsdiv = eval("document.getElementById('smallnews')");
      smallnewsdiv.appendChild(title);
      smallnewsdiv.appendChild(nibformtitle);
      smallnewsdiv.appendChild(nibformcontent);
      }


     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <h1>EG Editor</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the EG Editor, your one stop shop for making your EG email</p>
     <p>Please Fill out the form like you would any other internet form, press save when your done</p>
     <p>Once you've saved your content, you can then click on the link to the finished product, save the file as HTML (file->save as->html only option when saving), open in word and then Send to yourself (File->Send To->Mail Recipient) and biggity-bam you've got your issue of EG</p>
    <h2>Main Stories</h2>
    <p>Here is where you put in your stuff for your Main stories</p>
    <form name="form1" action="Egbuilder.asp" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Story One:</td>
    <td>Title: <input type="text" name="mainstory1_title" style="width: 220px"></td>
    <td>Content: <textarea cols="22" rows="7" name="mainstory1" style="width: 220px;"> </textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Story Two:</td>
    <td>Title: <input type="text" name="mainstory2_title" style="width: 220px"></td>
    <td>Content: <textarea cols="22" rows="7" name="mainstory2" style="width: 220px;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Story Three:</td>
    <td>Title: <input type="text" name="mainstory3_title" style="width: 220px"></td>
    <td>Content: <textarea cols="22" rows="7" name="mainstory3" style="width: 220px;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Story Four:</td>
    <td>Title: <input type="text" name="mainstory4_title" style="width: 220px"></td>
     <td>Content: <textarea cols="22" rows="7" name="mainstory4" style="width: 220px;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <h2>Promotions</h2>
    <p>If there's a promotion this week then tick the 'show promotion' box, Just pop your words into the box and then copy the Intranet link into the link box.</p>
   <p>Show Promotion? <input type="checkbox" name="promotioncheck" ></p>
   <p>Banner Text:<br>
   <textarea cols="22" rows="7" name="promotiontext" style="width: 400px;"></textarea></p>
   <p>Intranet Link: <br>
  <input type="text" name="promotionlink" style="width: 400px"></p>
  <div id="smallnews">
  <h2>News in Briefs</h2>
  <p>Here is where you add your smaller stories, you can add as many as you want. Just click the green plus button to add another box</p>
  <h3>Story 1</h3>
  <p>Title:<br>
  <input type="text" name="nib1_title" style="width: 400px"></p>
  <p>Content:<br>
 <textarea cols="22" rows="7" name="nib1_content" style="width: 400px;"></textarea>
  </p>
 </div>
 <p><a href="Javascript:addnib()" title="Press this button to add another button"><img src="images/add.jpg" alt="add button" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 0px">Add another Story</a><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="true"><input style="margin-left: 200px;" type="submit" value="Save" ></p>
</form>
</body>
 </html>
```

I'm sure it's really simple and I've just missed something basic but any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Please do not post your *entire* code and leave people with figuring out what you want to do. You're not even asking an actual question here, as far as I can see. More description, less code.

Comment: Sorry I'll expand on it. Basically My ASP code just loops through all the submitted form elements and then creates an XML file from them. I've tried to add a way to check if the checkbox in the HTML is checked by adding a Request.QueryString("promotioncheck") If statement but it doesn't pick up the changes. How should I change this so it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently retrieving promotioncheck from the Querystring, but you're POSTing the form so the value won't be in the QueryString collection.

Instead retrieve the value from the Form collection like so:

```
Request.Form("promotioncheck") = "on"
```

I can't remember what the default return value for a checkbox with no value attribute set is in classic asp, so double check "on" is being returned.